# I found a Stack Overflow Facebook page. Is it as official as it claims?

Tags: discussion, facebook

Recently a Facebook page named Stack Overflow, that has +200K likes, has shown some activity, specifically updating the profile picture and cover photo. It also claimed the username "officialstackoverflow".

I was wondering if it is really an *official* Facebook page created and maintained by Stack Exchange or just another fan page made by SO lovers.

This is the page I'm talking about: https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow

Comment: It looks pretty official to me, the content seems to be relevant.

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15815/stack-overflow-on-social-networks-linkedin-facebook-hi5-orkut

Comment: Only problem is my account on facebook is not going to match to my account here. I'll have to create a relevant Facebook account for it.

Comment: WTF why people have to spam even there?!

Comment: Why do people have to spam on Facebook? Hrm, what else *is* there on Facebook?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, that's our page. As you can tell, it's been a little .. quiet since being created in 2009, but folks are actively working on updating it / polishing it up and actually sharing stuff there.

Note, since 2008 several very dedicated users set up pages for Stack Overflow (and other sites) as well, since we didn't have any presence there to speak of. While they aren't *official*, they *probably* got permission from Jeff at some point in the past to go ahead with making something.

Answer (score 14):

This is indeed the official Facebook page for Stack Overflow and maintained by Stack Exchange, not a fan. There will be more consistent activity going forwards.

Comment: You're the first Stack Exchange employee I see without a diamond. You should ask for a refund.

Comment: Angela has our upgraded diamond, it's simply not visible to mere mortals. If you were to gaze upon it, this pinkish 'goo' sort of substance would start streaming out of your ears as you found yourself with the ability to breathe through your eyes. It wouldn't be pleasant. Refund indeed, you should be thankful.

Comment: It would be nice if employees had some distinguishing mark so we can easily spot official answers, pink goo notwithstanding.

Comment: @A.Webb Good idea! Perhaps you could post it as a feature request?

Comment: aggghhh all the posts are "Public"! That means no matter what I comment or like on that page, _every_ one of my "friends" will be notified about the activity in their news feed! Even colleagues, whom I tend to keep as contacts but with no visibility of my actual posts. _Please_ make it so that only people who like the page can see my activity on it...... Disappointed to see a tech firm make this mistake. **Or** does FB not allow this for pages (c.f. groups)? Wouldn't surprise me that much....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit simple solution, don't comment or like posts ;)

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Well, quite!